# segmentation faults with string.h into queue

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

Sorry noob question couldn't figure out which functions to use here.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Was gonna convert to c-string and write a whole mess of code but I bet there's a good way to do this.

Just trying to append A, B, and C to the end of a string and add it to queue, keep getting segmentation fault tho that terminates in a ??() function after string::assign() (according to debugger)

```
string a, b, c;
a = s.append("A");
b = s.append("B");
c = s.append("C");

q.add(a);
q.add(b);
q.add(c);
```

this too ends with segmentation fault.

```
q.add(s + "A");
q.add(s + "B");
q.add(s + "C");
```

Also problem with this is it uses the old, so I'll get:

```
teststringA
teststringAB
teststringABC
```

instead of expected

```
teststringA
teststringB
teststringC
```

Comment: Please post a [*complete* example that demonstrates your problem](http://sscce.org/). There should be no problem with the code you've posted.

Comment: the only thing that I do not see is where s is defined. Could you show us that?

Comment: If you are using the Standard Library `std::string` you should include `<string>`, not `<string.h>`. It doesn't look like you are using `std::queue` so you should post your queue code too.

Answer (score 0):

[**What is a segmentation fault?**](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html)

When your program runs, it has access to certain portions of memory. First, you have local variables in each of your functions; these are stored in the stack. Second, you may have some memory, allocated during runtime (using either malloc, in C, or new, in C++), stored on the heap (you may also hear it called the "free store"). Your program is only allowed to touch memory that belongs to it -- the memory previously mentioned. Any access outside that area will cause a segmentation fault. Segmentation faults are commonly referred to as segfaults.

your second problem is

```
q.add(s + "A"); // appends A to s hence teststringA
q.add(s + "B"); // teststringA + B hence teststringAB
q.add(s + "C"); //teststringAB + C hence teststringABC
```

refer document at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/

```
Append to string
The current string content is extended by adding an additional appending string at its end.

The arguments passed to the function determine this appending string:

string& append ( const string& str );
    Appends a copy of str.
```

example

```
// appending to string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str;
  string str2="Writing ";
  string str3="print 10 and then 5 more";

  // used in the same order as described above:
  str.append(str2);                       // "Writing "
  str.append(str3,6,3);                   // "10 "
  str.append("dots are cool",5);          // "dots "
  str.append("here: ");                   // "here: "
  str.append(10,'.');                     // ".........."
  str.append(str3.begin()+8,str3.end());  // " and then 5 more"
  str.append<int>(5,0x2E);                // "....."

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Writing 10 dots here: .......... and then 5 more.....
```